# Getting data from Firebase using User ID

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created Firebase database and each instance has a UID which is same as the one created from Firebase Authentication:

How do I read data by searching the UID?

[image]

I got the UID by:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
UID = currentUser.getUid();
```

How do I pass in the UID to retrieve everything from `Rack` ?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a query for that. Something like:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("busUsers");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("uID").equalTo(UID);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("DB", snapshot.getKey());
            Log.i("DB", snapshot.child("adminName").getValue(String.class));
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

The loop in `onDataChange` is needed because there may be multiple businesses with the same `uID` value. If that is not the case, consider using the `uID` value as the key for the nodes under `busUsers`.